# image not showing according to IF statement

Tags: javascript, html

Hello guys I am trying to change image between ford and ferrari the image changing works fine but the problem is according to if condition the initial picture should be of ferrari but it shows ford. My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
<script>
    function change_image()
    {
        var imgtext = document.getElementById('MyImage').alt;

        if(imgtext == "ford")
        {
            document.getElementById('MyImage').src = "ferrari.jpg";
            document.getElementById('MyImage').alt = "ferrari";
            document.getElementById('mytext').value = "FerrariCar"; 
        }else{
            document.getElementById('MyImage').src = "ford.jpg";
            document.getElementById('MyImage').alt = "ford";
            document.getElementById('mytext').value = "FordCar";
        }

    }
</script>
</head>

  <body>
<img id="MyImage" src="ford.jpg"  width="350" height="350" alt="ford">
<input type="text" id="mytext" value="FordCar">
<input type="button" value="change Image" onclick="change_image()">

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: According to html it is `ford` and your js function only runs on button click. Not sure what you expect here

Comment: You need to trigger the change_image() function. One way to achieve what you want is to change your body tag to call the function the first time the page is loaded.

<body onload="change_image()">

Comment: Thanks the page loading method worked !!

Answer (score 0):

Everything is behaving as expected.
the picture shows ford because the source of the image is initially ford.jpg

```
<img id="MyImage" src="ford.jpg"  width="350" height="350" alt="ford">
```

you have 2 options:

1. set the source of the image to Ferrary
2. run change_image() function on page load.
   this can be achieved by adding change_image() after the function.

Comment: i just added onload="change_image()" in the body tag and it worked fine thanks for the answer !